# Is there an OpenStack distro based on Xen vs. KVM running in PV mode?

Tags: openstack, xen

The research group that I'm in has a technical requirement for OpenStack to be running on XenServer instead of the more popular KVM. I have looked around but have not found a distro with that mix. Has anybody heard of anything like this? trying to make this environment as supportable as possible.

Thank you for your time.